# How do I edit Confluence Cloud wiki pages via html/css source code?

Tags: html, css, confluence

At work, we use Confluence Cloud. I looked through the site, and found the following info about the version of the Confluence Cloud that we are using:

License Information for Confluence Cloud

Confluence 1000.0.0-d84982f3b61f

Copyright © 2003 - 2017 Atlassian Corporation Pty Ltd.

The version we are using seems kind of limited.

It seems like I can only edit pages in Confluence Cloud using the standard editor

I wanted to edit the page as an html/css source, but I can't figure out how to do so. Does anyone know if the version of Confluence Cloud that I'm using gives users the ability to edit html/css source code for a particular wiki page?  If yes, could someone please tell me what steps I have to take in order to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Confluence does not allow you to edit as HTML / CSS.

edit: Confluence does allow administrators to edit using HTML / CSS: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/styling-confluence-with-css-166528400.html However, I do not know if these features are available on this particular version of Confluence.

Comment: Thanks. Is that Only for Confluence Cloud?  Or Is that for all versions or types of installations for confluence?  ( see: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/styling-fonts-in-confluence-174751968.html )

Comment: You just opened up a whole new world for me. I'm not sure about your version of Confluence Cloud, but it seems that those with administrator priveleges are able to add custom HTML as well as CSS. I found that on this document: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/styling-confluence-with-css-166528400.html (I have never had administrator access to Confluence). I can't find too much information about the particular version you are using, so if the steps in these articles aren't working I would suggest contacting support.

Comment: Thanks.  You might want to re-edit your answer to reflect the confluence technical doc